# Put data via GSON to RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, gson

I would like to put the fetched data from my server to the RecyclerView, but nothing is shown in the RecyclerView.

This is my JSON structure:

```
{
"userlist": [{
    "user": {
        "firstname": "Marcelina",
        "city": "North Alvera",
        "id": {
            "low": 35392,
            "high": 0
        },
        "lastname": "Ernser"
    }
}, {
    "user": {
        "firstname": "Laury",
        "city": "South Lottie",
        "id": {
            "low": 51009,
            "high": 0
        },
        "lastname": "McClure"
    }
}]}
```

First of all I generated the POJO class (with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org), resulting the following classes:

Userlist.java

```
public class Userlist {

@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private User user;

public Userlist(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}}
```

User.java

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("firstname")
@Expose
private String firstname;
@SerializedName("city")
@Expose
private String city;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Id id;
@SerializedName("lastname")
@Expose
private String lastname;

public User(String firstname, String city, Id id, String lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.city = city;
    this.id = id;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public Id getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Id id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}}
```

Id.java

```
public class Id {

@SerializedName("low")
@Expose
private int low;
@SerializedName("high")
@Expose
private int high;

public Id(int low, int high) {
    this.low = low;
    this.high = high;
}

public int getLow() {
    return low;
}

public void setLow(int low) {
    this.low = low;
}

public int getHigh() {
    return high;
}

public void setHigh(int high) {
    this.high = high;
}}
```

And finally, this is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://...";

private ArrayList<Userlist> userList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_user);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //LayoutManager
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Adapter
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(userList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    getAllUsers();
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private void getAllUsers() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(BASE_URL + "user")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String responseStr = response.body().string();
            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            List<Userlist> userList = new ArrayList<>();
            userList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(responseStr, Userlist.class));
            System.out.print(responseStr);
            response.body().close();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}}
```

Now the question is how do handle the fetched data the right way. I´ve read much about the AsyncTask, but which solution is the best to get json-data, parse it with GSON and put it into the RecyclerView?!

Thanks in advance guys.

Cheers Andy

Comment: GSON with retrofit 2

Comment: You can use retrofit or volley..

Comment: there is no *best* way. Everyone has his own favorite.

Comment: hey guys! thanks for your answers :) to get more precisely: my question was not about how to fetch the data (which HTTP-client) but how to "work" with it respectively if it´s advisable to make an AsyncTask in which i make the requests...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  private ArrayList<Userlist> userList;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
  private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_user);

     recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
     LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 
     false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

  ButterKnife.bind(this);
  getAllUsers();
 }


 private void getAllUsers() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

     Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(BASE_URL + "user")
        .build();

     client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        String responseStr = response.body().string();
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        //List<Userlist> userList = new ArrayList<>();
         Userlist userlist = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(responseStr),Userlist.class));
        userList.add(userlist);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(userList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.print(responseStr);
        response.body().close();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       } 
     });
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to notify adapter changes before attaching the array userlist in the recyclerView adapter.

Correct your code by creating the Recyclerview Instance then attach the userList back to the RecyclerAdapter instance before notifying changes to the recycler adapter.

As shown below

```
        userList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(responseStr, Userlist.class));
        /*As shown here*/
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(your_activity.this, userList);

        System.out.print(responseStr);
        response.body().close();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```